# iOS UITextView wont resize

Tags: ios, height, uitextview

This is really strange.  I have a UITextView properly connected with an OBOutlet.  In my viewDidLoad I am updating it's text like so:

```
[tvDescription setText:@"This is some sample text "];
```

Then just for testing, I try to resize it with:

```
[tvDescription setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];
```

The text updates fine, but no matter what I put in the sizes for setFrame, nothing happens, it stays its normal size.  Its like it is locked.

tvDescription is the UITextView, which is 301 width and 104 height in the nib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try taking a look at the Auto Resize Mask of the text view - Make sure it doesn't resize when it's displayed. If you're using auto-layout, make sure that the constraints match what you're trying to do.

Other than that, just make sure your outlets are hooked up (seems they are because of the text update) and it should work.

Comment: I didnt see this before, in the file inspector tab there is an option:  Use Autolayout.  I had to uncheck that.  Even when I set the contraints with autolayout on, it didnt work.  But with autolayout disabled all is good now, thanks.